# Check MS SQL Server Running or Exist?

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

How to check MS SQL Server Running or Exist using Script.
I have below script, not happy with script, is there any smart way to find?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import inspect

MSSQL_ServerName = 'DESKTOP-R27RCUDD'

try:
    Driver = 'driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0';
    engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://' + MSSQL_ServerName + '/master?' + Driver)
    Inspector = inspect(engine)
except:
    print('SQL Server NOT Found')
```